# Xamarin Prism cannot navigate with parameters

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

for my app i create my own buttons using a frame and adding a tapgesture to it. here i use the navigation of prism to go to a specific page with a parameter. however. the viewmodel i'm going to does not trigger the Navigated to method. here is some code.

during debugging it seems that the adding of the parameters is no problem. however the constructor for the viewmodel is called instead.

button

```
public class FolderButton : Frame
{
    public FolderButton(Folder folder, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        var navParams = new NavigationParameters();
        navParams.Add("folder", folder);
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            Command = new Command(async () => { await navigationService.NavigateAsync("FolderInventory", navParams); }),
        });

        BackgroundColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        var thickness = new Thickness();
        thickness.Bottom = 10;
        thickness.Left = 10;
        thickness.Right = 10;
        thickness.Top = 10;
        Margin = thickness;
        CornerRadius = 5;

        var completeStack = new StackLayout();
        var imgStack = new StackLayout();
        imgStack.Padding = thickness;
        imgStack.Children.Add(new Image { Source = "folder.png" });
        completeStack.Children.Add(imgStack);
        var lblStack = new StackLayout();
        lblStack.Padding = thickness;
        lblStack.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = folder.Name,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start
        });
        completeStack.Children.Add(lblStack);

        Content = completeStack;
    }
}
```

called viewmodel

```
public class FolderInventoryViewModel : BindableBase, INavigatedAware
{
    public Folder Folder => _folder;

    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private Folder _folder;
    private readonly ISQLiteService _sqlService;
    private List<Frame> _buttons;

    public List<Frame> Buttons
    {
        get => _buttons;
        set => _buttons = value;
    }

    public FolderInventoryViewModel(Folder folder, INavigationService navigationService, ISQLiteService sqlService)
    {
        _folder = folder;
        _sqlService = sqlService;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        GetItemsForFolder();
    }

    private void GetItemsForFolder()
    {
        var itemList = _sqlService.GetAllFolderItems(Folder.Name);

        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            var itemButton = new ItemButton(_navigationService, item);
            _buttons.Add(itemButton);
        }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters["folder"] is Folder folder)
        {
            _folder = folder;
        }

    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters["folder"] is Folder folder)
        {
            _folder = folder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is that Prism instantiates the ViewModel by resolving the dependencies (INavigationService and ISQLiteService) and injecting them through constructor. After that Prism will call OnNavigatedTo with the params you specified. So in this case I think you can drop the "folder" param of the constructor. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the essence of using the framework. To properly use the Prism with its `NavigationParameters` you first properly maintain the MVVM idea behind it.

E.g.

```
<Button Command="{Binding testCommand}" text="TestButton"/>
```

Your ViewModel (Pardon about this, you need to inject NavigationService to your ViewModel's constructor)

```
private DelegateCommand _testCommand;
public DelegateCommand testCommand =>
        _testCommand?? (_testCommand= new DelegateCommand(ExecuteTest));
private void ExecuteTest()
{
    NavigationParameters navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters();
    navigationParameters.Add("yourParameterId", value);
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("YourPage", navigationParameters);
}
```

And then onto your next page

Inherit INavigationAware to your NextPage : `YourNextPage: BaseViewModel, INavigationAware`

INavigationAware has 3 methods NavigatingTo, NavigatedTo, NavigatedFrom

Inside OnNavigatedTo you can call the parameters you have passed

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    //You can check if parameters has value before passing it inside

    if(parameters.ContainsKey("YourParameterId")
    {
         yourItem = (dataType)parameters[YourParameterId];
    }
}
```

Also note: The constructor will always be called first before the Navigating methods

Comment: i tried what u said. to make it more mvvm. needs a bit more work. but atm i get an error from the code.         public DelegateCommand<int> FolderClick => _folderClick?? (_folderClick = new DelegateCommand<int>(OnFolderClick));
        private List<Folder> _folders;

        public void OnFolderClick(int count)
        {
            var navParams = new NavigationParameters();
            navParams.Add("folder", _folders[count]);
            _navigationService.NavigateAsync("FolderInventory", navParams);
        }
this is what i got right now

Comment: @BjornFontaine Have you fixed it? Sorry for replying late, been busy since it's the launch of our App. Now I am clueless what you are trying to do, first, what is the error? Cause it maybe because of the parameter you are passing to. Sorry, I thought you were just passing parameters normally.